# How to set Postgres username and password in the Flask Peewee ORM?

Tags: python, postgresql, ubuntu, flask, peewee

I'm building a website using the Python [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) framework and the [Peewee ORM](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and PostgreSQL as a database. This worked fine when developing on my Mac. I now moved the installation to my Ubuntu 12.04 desktop to do some testing on Linux and I now run into trouble with Postgresql. On my Mac, the postgres server didn't seem to require a user and password (good for devving, bad for production). On Ubuntu it now says

```
OperationalError: FATAL:  role "kramer65" does not exist
```

kramer65 is my normal username in Ubuntu , so it should be obvious that postgres doesn't know it. I can log into psql using the postgres user, but I don't know how to add it to peewee. I've got a config file in which I have:

```
DATABASE = {
    'name': 'mydb',
    'engine': 'playhouse.postgres_ext.PostgresqlExtDatabase'
}
```

I tried adding `'password': 'mypassword'` and `'username': 'myusername'` to it, but then it says `OperationalError: invalid connection option "username"`.

Any idea how I can add the username and password to peewee to connect to my PostgreSQL database? All tips are welcome!

Comment: I never heard of peewee nor worked with it but what about the example postgres connection from the [github example](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/blob/master/examples/analytics/app.py#L52)?

Comment: And since peewee seems to use psycopg2 for Postgres connectivity, all of their connection options should apply

Comment: @DrColossos - How stupid! It turned out to be 'user' instead of 'username'. Thanks for the tip! If you answer the question I can mark your answer as Accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never heard of peewee nor worked with it but what about the [example postgres connection from the github](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/blob/master/examples/analytics/app.py#L52). And since peewee seems to use psycopg2 for Postgres connectivity, all of their connection options should apply.

You need to use `'user': 'yourusername'` instead of `'username': 'yourusername'`.